# ReactJS Production Deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, webpack

I currently have production web app (PHP+AngularJS) & Java/Spring backend. Basically it is a web app making lots and lots of REST Api calls to Java backend and rendering that data on web forms. I use Apache Web 2.0 to host the frontend and Tomcat for the backend

Planning to migrate to ReactJS, Java/Spring will still be the backend. I need some guidance on following

1. Best Web Server to use to deploy React (Build/Deploy controlled through CD/CI, Jenkins)
2. Any specific frameworks and/or components that needs to be added and installed to support this web app.
3. Best Testing framework to use for React which will work with the CI/CD pipeline.
4. Can all this be containerized (docker/kubernetes) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Any server that servers static files (express, apacha, nginx, etc) can handle a react app.
2. You'll need webpack to build the project (transpile/minify/optimise)
3. You'll need a test runner (i suggest jest from facebook) and a library to test/render you application on each unit test. Use [react-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library) (simple, dynamic and easy to use).
4. Totally!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you point me to some documents/tutorials for points 3 & 4.

Comment: I don't actually know much resources about docker, so i can't point you to that direction. For test runner (https://jestjs.io/), react-testing-library(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDkSaCgR8g4)